# Modify code to check for duplicate entries in select box

Tags: javascript

I have the below, it dynamically adds a new value option into a selectbox. The problem i have is that it does not check for duplicate entries before adding new options into the select box.
Is there a way i can make a change to my code so it will alert the user that a duplicate entry is found and to stop adding the same option value?

```
function refadd() {

var val = document.getElementById('docsref').value

    if (val != "") {

        var select = document.getElementById('docsref_list');

        var option = document.createElement('option');

        option.text = value

        select.add(option,select.option)

        select.selectedIndex = select.options.length - 1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best is to **loop** through all existing options and check if you had a match.
The loop would be added so it appears **BEFORE** your IF condition. 
If a match is found you could notify the user (e.g. alert ) and then execute a "**return**" statement.

Something like the below:

```
function refadd() 
{
    var value = document.getElementById('docsref').value
    if (value != "") 
    {
        var select = document.getElementById('docsref_list');
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        var flag = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < select.length; i++)
        {
        if(select[i].value == value)
        {   
            flag = 1;
        }
        }
        if(flag == 1)
        {
        alert('Value is duplicate.');
        }
        else
        {
        option.text = value;
        select.add(option,select.option);
        select.selectedIndex = select.options.length - 1;
        }

    }
}
```

If your HTML is like:

```
<div>
    <input type = "text" name = "docsref" id = "docsref" style = "width:100px;"/>
    <input type = "button" name = "addValues" id = "addValues" value = "AddValues" onClick = "refadd();"/>
    </br>
    <select id = "docsref_list">
    <option value = "1">1</option>
    <option value = "2">2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
using jQuery...

    function refadd() {    
    var val = $("#docsref").val();
        if (val != "") {
    for(var i = 0; i < select.length; i++)
        {
        if(select[i].value == value)
        {   
            alert("can't add.");
            return false;
        }
        }
        var ob = new Option("option text", "value");
        $(ob).html("option text");
        $("#selectList").append(ob);
        }
    }
```